# ¿Que hace el return en esta funcion?

Tags: c++, nodos

```
void MostrarArbol(Nodo *arbol, int cont){
if(arbol == NULL){
    return;
}
else{
    MostrarArbol(arbol->der, cont+1);
    
    for(int i=0; i<cont; i++){
        cout<<"   ";
    }
    cout<<arbol->dato<<"\n";
    MostrarArbol(arbol->izq, cont+1);
}
```

Cuando quiero mostrar un arbol binario de busqueda,en la parte del if, entiendo que es para que la primera vez que recorramos el arbol en caso de que este vacio, pero despues de llegar a un nodo "hoja" que las partes izquierda y derecha estan en null, tengo una duda, la funcion se vuelve a llamar cuando entra en el null y en este caso si se ejecuta el primer if, pero cuando se ejecuta el return, ¿a donde me retorna?, he pensado que me retorna a el nodo anterior pero no creo que ese sea el caso, ya que volveria a llamarse entrando a el null de la hoja y si retorna a el nodo anterior volvera a la izquierda donde tambien es null haciendo algo que nunca termina, mi duda es, ¿para que sirve ese return en el primer if?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `return` es para "salir" de la función, la función tiene un valor de retorno de `void`, es decir no retorna nada, si tu función tiene más líneas de código luego del `else` no las ejecutará y esto ahorrará recursos y tiempo en tu programa.

Por cierto, cuándo dices:

> ¿A donde me retorna?

Los `return` no te "devuelven" a ningún lado, finalizan la ejecución de la función y por lo tanto se vuelve al punto de llamada. Mejor pregúntate:

> ¿Qué me retorna?

En este caso no retorna nada por el tipo de la función y el parámetro de `return` vacío.

Comment: Los `return` salen de la función, así que la ejecución **vuelve al punto de llamada**.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Por su puesto, pero eso pasa con una función que no tiene `return`, es algo que tiene que ver con lo que es una función en sí, que al terminar su ejecución (por ejemplo porque ya se porque devolvió un valor o ya no hay más líneas) vuelve al punto de llamada . Pensé que el OP podía pensar en hacer un "retorno" por la traducción del keyword, cuando en realidad el `return` hace referencia a *return a value* (devolver un valor), en vez de "retornar".

Comment: Piense lo que piense el OP, no es verdad que una función no retorna a ningún sitio. Todas las funciones (tanto si tienen `return` como si no) retornan al punto de llamada, devuelvan lo que devuelvan.

Comment: Lo que piensa el OP es importante, la pregunta la hace él, la respuesta es para él y se hace bajo el contexto que el pregunte. Edité la pregunta para aclarar que **finalizar la función** devuelve el código al punto de retorno.

Comment: no he dicho que lo que piense el OP no sea importante. Lo que he dicho es que un `return` devuelve (retorna) la ejecución al punto de llamada de la función (ergo, es mentira que, como **decías**, no retorne a ningún sitio) y eso será así independientemente de lo que piense el OP.